# Refrigerator relay has a circuit board?

Tags: circuit-analysis, solid-state-relay, triac, solid-state-devices

My fridge stopped cooling and kept hearing a click noise every 2-4 minutes. Researching led me to understand the start relay is nothing more than a PTC resistor that cuts the start winding once compressor kicks on.

Seemed simple enough so I open mine and it's more complex with a circuit board AND a PTC overload separate.

Now the circuit board has a triac but what's puzzling is only Line and Neutral 115v are fed into the whole assembly. There isn't a control line going from mainboard of the fridge to the gate of the triac.

So I'm puzzled to its operation. Does anyone know what the circuit board is for?
[image: relay/overload assembly minus the run capacitor that plugs into the two large female slots] [image][image]

Comment: Are there any parts underneath where T1 is folded over?

Comment: Also, can you get us a higher-res image of the bottom of the board?

Comment: No it's only folded over to fit into the housing

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Will do tomorrow

Comment: Also, where do L and N connect to the board at?

Comment: L connects through a PTC which then goes into the run capacitor which connects to the circuit board. I believe the common pin on the compressor completes the path through its internal windings back to the N

Comment: Ah, perhaps you could mark the board images with where the L and N terminals are? (The layout artist spaced off silkscreening which one was which.)

Comment: Maybe a potential relay that energizes the starting winding. When the potential across the start capacitor drops enough the triac turns off. LS = Line Start (?) is switched by the triac.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany so it's made in a way that 120v is sent to the gate of the triac to trigger it on?

Comment: @ohmmy the triac only requires some mA at a couple volts. The 150n film cap is probably involved. So it turns on immediately then off after the compressor starts.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a failed module or a bad compressor. To help understand what is involved the compressor is a single phase motor directly coupled to a compressor. This is then placed in a sealed can with normally 3 pins coming out. These pins are Common, Start, and Run. Starting of this type of motor is done with a centripetal  switch however the reliability of this in the compressor can is very limited. Why, the refrigeration system circulates oil and refrigerant. For this reason it is controlled from outside the compressor can. You can add power to the run winding and start winding at the same time and a few seconds later disconnect the start winding. I built a manual start box that did exactly this for testing compressors.

Your system probably has a capacity tube (cap tube) that meters refrigerant into the evaporator (coil in refrigerator). This evaporates absorbing heat from the box and then is returned to the compressor where it is compressed and run across the condenser (this gets hot) and starts all over again. When the compressor turns off it can take upto 10 minutes for the pressures to equalize from the input to the output of the compressor. The motor does not have a lot of starting torque nor can it start by applying power. You have to energize both the run and start windings. When it has determined the compressor has reached some predefined speed it turns the start winding off and it goes from there.

If for some reason the compressor draws to much current for a period of time it is switched off and tried again later. If it gets to warm it is shut down. The older units used a bimetallic thermal sensing switch that was mounted to the compressor. For obvious reasons we called it a clickson.

Your module is probably responsible for controlling the start winding, failure will cause the compressor to fault and get hot. It will get hot if both windings are on constantly or if the run winding is on and the motor is not rotating. The Clickson is probably cycling causing the noise. I would suggest replacing that first as it is the easiest and not super expensive. If it continues to click after replacement then you need to get professional help from a HVAC technician.

Without being there I will recommend you change that module and all should be well.

Answer (score 0):

electronic start device that replaces thermodisk type (disk type much more reliable)-22uf capacitor on board gets sick and causes circuit to not fire triac to send power to compressor start winding-causes overload in assembly to repeatedly open/close (click)